# C++11 mixing enum class and unsigned int in switch case will not compile

Tags: c++, c++11, enum-class

Why doesn't this code compile, and what can I do to make it compile?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum class myEnum : unsigned int
{
    bar = 3
};

int main() {
    // your code goes here

    unsigned int v  = 2;
    switch(v)
    {
        case 2:
        break;

        case myEnum::bar:
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

ideone:

https://ideone.com/jTnVGq

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:18:16: error: could not convert 'bar' from 'myEnum' to 'unsigned int'
   case myEnum::bar:
```

Fails to build in GCC and Clang, works in MSVC 2013.

Comment: `static_cast<myEnum>(2)`

Comment: Strongly typed enums are strongly typed, and have no implicit conversions to an integral type.

Comment: I thought ": unsigned int" allowed this?

Comment: No, that just means the enum will be stored in an unsigned int. The enum itself is still strongly typed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The whole purpose of the `enum class` was so that its members couldn't be compared directly to `int`s, ostensibly improving the type safety of C++11 relative to C++03. Remove `class` from `enum class` and this will compile.

To quote Lord Bjarne:

> (An) `enum class` (a scoped enumeration) is an `enum` where the enumerators are within scope of the enumeration and no implicit conversions to other types are provided.

Comment: I daresay you exaggerated about 'whole purpose'. There's another reason to use `enum class` -- to restrict enumerators to a nested namespace.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use such a syntax:

```
enum class Test { foo = 1, bar = 2 };
int main()
{
  int k = 1;
  switch (static_cast<Test>(k)) {
    case Test::foo: /*action here*/ break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that keeps using `enum class` is to add a new field that represents a value of 2 to `myEnum`. Then you can change `unsigned int v` to `myEnum v`.

```
enum class myEnum : unsigned int
{
    foo = 2,
    bar = 3
};

int main() {
    myEnum v = myEnum::foo;
    switch(v)
    {
        case myEnum::foo:
        break;

        case myEnum::bar:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

An example of **enum** using classes and switch case , this is the proper way to call an **enum** class from another class.

```
class MyClass 
{
public:

enum class colors {yellow , blue , green} ; 

};


int main ()
{

Myclass::colors c = Myclass::colors::yellow;
 
switch(c)
{
case Myclass::colors::yellow:
cout <<"This is color yellow \n"
case Myclass::colors::blue:
cout <<"This is color blue\n"

}

return 0 ; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike, the question is asking why it doesn't compile as well as how to fix. Perhaps edit your answer to address that question.